# addField in SolrInputDocument

Tags: solr, solrj

When I add field addField("category","cat1"); it doesn't appear in the search result xml , and there's just 2 fields to be added which is "id" and "name" , could any body tell me how to add another field and to appear in the xml result

Comment: can you post the code? did you add the "category" field in schema.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Define the field you want to add in schema.xml and make multivalued true in the case of using "ADDFIELD".

Answer (score 0):

in your schema.xml, if you set a field as "stored", it will show up in the results

```
    <field name="internal_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="desc" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```